# Why do I need lambda to apply functions to a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a Pandas data frame and am attempting to pass a function over the entries in one column using the apply() function.

My function is of the form:

```
def foo(Y):
    #accepts a pandas data frame
    #carries out some search on the text in each row of the dataframe
    #groups successful searches
    #return a new column as a pandas series
```

My dataframe is of the form:

```
    Info    WN    RN
0    XX    YY    ZZ    
1    AA    BB    CC
2    JJ    KK    LL
```

I attempt to execute:

```
df['SR'] = (df['Info'].apply(foo(x)))
```

My error is as follows:

```
File "<ipython-input-11-ae54015436d8>", line 1, in <module>
df['SR'] = (df['Info'].apply(foo(x))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

But if I use:

```
df['SR'] = (df['Info'].apply(lambda x:foo(x)))
```

It works fine.

I understand how Lambda works (at least I thought I did). I don't understand why I need it.

Why do I need lambda to successfully pass the function over the data frame? Shouldn't the apply() function do that by definition?

Or is it that I am effectively doing it the other way around i.e. passing my data frame into the function, and returning some output, rather than iteratively applying the function to the data frame (if that makes sense)?

Can anyone offer any insight?

My sincere thanks!

Comment: In this case the `lambda` is not necessary: `df['SR'] = df['Info'].apply(foo)` would just work

Comment: You don't **need** a lambda, but `df['Info'].apply(foo(x))` doesn't make any sense as syntax since x isn't defined, you wanted to do `(df['Info'].apply(foo))` instead. Just pass `apply()` the function. Don't try to write a function call inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda is unnecessary, you can just do

```
df['SR'] = df['Info'].apply(foo)
```

here it will still work

Comment: That's odd. Because when I do the exact same here, it doesn't. I will update my Q with the full foo contents for clarity.

Comment: My apologies: you are correct. That does solve the issue. My next question would be why would the lambda be needed at all? (but perhaps that is a more general question suited to somewhere else)

Comment: The thing to understand is that `lambda`'s are just syntactic sugar for a normal function definition: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions, they have a restriction that can only accept a single arg, it's down to personal preference to be honest there isn't a situation where a `lambda` does something that a normal func cannot do

Comment: Appreciate the link. I'll have a read and mooch around some other questions on SO to get a feel. Thanks for your help.